# How to adjust exposure, white balance, ISO, and focal length in react-native-vision-camera?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I'm working on a project using react-native-vision-camera and I need to adjust the exposure, white balance, ISO, and focal length parameters for the camera. However, I'm not sure how to do this using the API provided by react-native-vision-camera.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to adjust these parameters? Are there any specific functions or methods that I should use in the react-native-vision-camera API? I only found the parameters related to these in photoFile, but it seems that these are the parameters of the finished photo, and you can't adjust these parameters during the photo taking process. I tried to change the parameter of metadata['{Exif}'] such as `photo.metadata['{Exif}'].WhiteBalance = 8000;` but nothing changed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!